# toggle disappears after few seconds on Type="Submit" input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, toggle

I am new to html+jquery problem, however, I think I managed to creat a html page where we input file using following code:

```
<!--Input file-->
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <label>Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" maxlength="90" /></label>  
    <input  type="submit" class="results" onclick="showHint();myFunction();"  name = "submit"  value="Submit"/>
```

Then, the input file is fed to php to get the result. This part is perfectly workin.However, I am unable to perform toggle(.show()) effect on submit button so that the result appearce only when input file is submitted. I tried following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHint(event){

    $("#hint-toggle").toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
        }
</script>
```

but the  result div appearance for few seconds only. I would appreciate any suggestion or help.

```
<div id="hint-toggle" style="display: none">
                    <p>OUTPUT</p>
         </div>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to send the form to the server? If so, you should post that code as well. If not, your page will reload because of the regular form submit. The latter seems to be your current problem.

Comment: That's what happens when you submit a form, it reloads the page and any changes made with javascript are lost ?

Comment: I am not familiar with AJAX method send. please redirect to some example (demo)page.